# Cannot pass mongoose data to view Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

How can i pass my data to the view, i'm using "mongoose-simple-random" to pick 5 random food from my database, i want to pass them on my Jade code, but i don't know how, can someone help me, this is my code:

jade almuerzo.jade

```
extends layout

block takami
    .container-fluid
        .row
            .col-md-12
                h3 Guardar  almuerzo
                form(method="post", action="/almuerzo")
                    fieldset.form-group
                        label(for='nombre') Nombre de Comida
                        input#nombre.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Nombre', name='nombre')
                    fieldset.form-group
                        label(for='tipo') Tipo de comida
                        input#tipo.form-control(type='text', placeholder='tipo de comida', name='tipo')
                    button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit
    .container-fluid
        .row
            .row
                .col-md-12
                    h3 Menu de Almuerzos
            .row
                .col-md-2
                     h3 Lunes
                         h4 Comida
                             ul.list-group
                                 each almuer in almuerzovar
                                     li.list-group-item = almuer.nombre
                             hr/
                         h4 Bebidas
                             ul.list-group
                                li.list-group-item Horchata
                                li.list-group-item Horchata2
```

almuerzo.js (My router with ExpressJS)

```
var express = require('express');
var almuerzoSchema = require('../models/almuerzos');
var router = express.Router();


/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
    almuerzoSchema.findRandom({}, {}, {limit: 5}, function(err, results) {
        if (!err) {
            response.render('almuerzo',{almuerzovar: results});
        }
    });


});
router.post("/", function (req,resp) {
    var objAlmuerzo = new almuerzoSchema({
        nombre: req.body.nombre,
        tipo: req.body.tipo

    });
    objAlmuerzo.save(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }else{
        resp.render('almuerzo');
        }
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

With "console.log(results)" it shows the data (5 items random)

Comment: Can't see the form action in the express.

Comment: /* GET users listing. */ there "findrandom" i want to pass the "results" to my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parse result, it needs to be mapped in Object

```
// ES 6  way for Node v 4.x + 
let parseResult = (result) => {
  return result.map((item) => item.toObject())
}
```

EDITED:

```
// for ES 5
function parseResult(result) {
  return result.map(function(item) {
    return result.toObject()
  }
}
```

This should do. The object is MongoDb object and it needs to be converted in JS object. I hope this helps

Then your GET request becomes

```
router.get('/', function (request, response) {
// parseResult Function should be pasted here // TRY ES5 i guess you have node v.0.10
almuerzoSchema.findRandom({}, {}, {limit: 5}, function(err, results) {
    if (!err) {
        response.render('almuerzo',{almuerzovar: parseResult(results)});
    }
});
```

Here You can see how to use 
    Model.toObject()

find the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) here

Comment: Sorry i'm new on this, how can i parse the results? i tried the above code(get request) you made and it doesn't work.

Comment: what was the error !?
Actually the MongoDB returns its Collection Object, we need to Convert MongoDB object to Javascript Object, in order for other Functions to use it as Object.

Comment: Now i get "TypeError: result.toObject is not a function" do you know why?